# How to display additional info in MarionetteJS ItemView depending if user is logged in?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a CompositeView with a list of ItemViews. The same collection is rendered for both states, when a user is logged in, and when a user is logged out.

The ItemView looks roughly like:

```
<div class="title">  
  {{ title }} 
</div>
{{#if MA.currentUser }}
  Add Review
{{/if}}
```

With the JavaScript:

```
MA.Views.Items.Movie = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: 'items/movie',
  className: 'movie'
});
```

However, this does not seem to display the expected 'Add Review'.

Any suggestions what could be done in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the template will only have access to the data that is passed to it. By default this is the model which is serialized by `serializeData` in the View Class which ItemView inherits. You can add additional data by using templateHelpers or writing a custom serializeData(may be other ways also).

### Template Helpers

template helpers in a `ItemView` could be like:

```
templateHelpers: {
  MA: function(){
    return MA; //Unknown if having the same function name as the global will effect it
  }
}
```

In your item view. See [marionette docs template helper](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md#accessing-data-within-the-helpers)

Template helpers can be a function, object literal or object.

### serializeData

For serializeData you just overwrite the `serializeData` method in your ItemView's Class.

```
serializeData: function(){
return {
  "some attribute": "some value"
}
```

Worth noting that this would require you to serialize your model also. [marionette docs serializeData](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.itemview.md#itemview-serializedata)

### Conclusion

`templateHelpers` may turn out to be the simplest answer and probably what they were intended for.